# Force 'save as' svg files

Tags: php

I've got the following file:

download.php

```
<?php 

$filename = $_GET["filename"];

if ($filename) {
$path = "/svg_files/".$filnavn."";
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  // For Gecko browsers mainly
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)) . ' GMT');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');  // For download resume
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));  // File size
header('Content-Encoding: none');
header('Content-Type: application/svg');  // Change this mime type if the file is not PDF
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);  // Make the browser display the Save As dialog
}
?>
```

It's located in the svg_files folder. But when I run:

myweb.com/svg_files/download.php?filename=file.svg

I just get an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to output the content of the file to the browser.. 
Use `readfile` or `file_get_contents` and `echo` or something similar.

As a sidenote: Be aware of so called directory traversal attacks. You might wanna take some precautions.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack